# Error al vincular cuenta de pago con Facebook Audience Network

Tags: facebook, admob

estoy tratando de configurar los datos que pide facebook para poder monetizar una app con los anuncios de Facebook Audience Network. Ya tengo mi app en la Playstore y ya llené todos los datos en mi cuenta de Facebook Developer,etc. También ya llené los datos de pago que me solicitan, en donde en teoría me llegarían los pagos de lo que pueda generar con los anuncios en mi app. Pero al momento de intentar Vincular estos datos de pago con mi "propiedad", es decir mi app, me pone el mensaje :

"Algunas plataformas no están disponibles en la región de la cuenta de pago facebook"

o también este otro:

"Esta plataforma no se admite en la región de esta cuenta de pago."

Cabe mencionar que intenté llenando 2 veces mis datos de pago cada una con un banco diferente.

Alguien sabe si en México no es posible realizar este tipo de vinculación ni monetización de apps por medio de Facebook Audience?

Comment: Hola lo pudiste resolver?, estoy pasando por lo mismo

Comment: Igual tengo el mismo problema desde hace 1 año, pensé que ya se había arreglado